# How search for a file beginning with either a or z and ending with a or z?

Tags: files, find, directory, search, file-search

I attempted `find -name 'a*' 'z*' '*a' '*z'`

but it gave me the error code `find: paths must precede expression: z*`

I know how to find files starting with a though z, or ending with a-z, but not starting with specific letters.

Comment: The error is because you can't combine multiple criteria this way. To specify that you want `-name` to be either `a*` or `z*`, you should say: `-name 'a*' -o -name 'z*'`. Of course 1_CR gave you the correct answer for your particular case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question, you are possibly overcomplicating it.
This should do

```
find your_directory -type f -name '[az]*[az]'
```

This omits files whose name is a single letter `a` or `z`. If you also want to include them, you need to specify another pattern: the name must match either `[az]*[az]` or `[az]`.

```
find your_directory -type f \( -name '[az]*[az]' -o -name '[az]' \)
```

Comment: @Gilles, thank you for addressing the corner case

Comment: `find . '(' -name 'a*' -o -name 'z*' ')' -a '(' -name '*a' -o -name '*z' ')'` is more similar to what @linux8807 was originally trying to express, and it also catches the corner case.

Comment: Or `find -name '[az]*' -a -name '*[az]'`

Comment: Wouldn't find -name '[az]*' find files starting with az? That's how I interpreted that.

Comment: @linux8807, `find -name '[az]*'` finds files starting with either `a` or `z`. Pattern matching with `find` is based on shell pattern matching, so if you can get it to work with the shell on the command line, it should work similarly with `find`

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm in school and the question my professor had for me was exactly "Now, suppose you want to list all the files in that same directory whose names start with a or z and end with a or z? " I've tried the answers given to me because I cannot find the help needed in my lessons or the Linux Bible. I first attempted with find ./directory '(' -name 'a*' -o -name 'z*' ')' -a '(' -name '*a' -o -name '*z' ')' which was considered incorrect them I attempted find ./directory -name '[az]*' '*[az]' and still it was incorrect. Any ideas on what my professor could be asking for exactly?

Comment: @linux8807, have you tried `find  -name '[az]*[az]'`

Comment: Another example based on @iruvar 's answer: `find ./ -type f -name 'file_name*.ext'`. Thanks! =D